# When I'm logged in I can see elements that disappear when I'm not logged in as Admin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, sections

I changed some sections in my Wordpress website and also added some.
The really strange thing is that when I am logged in and I see the website in the logged in view I can see the sections but when I'm not logged in I can't see that, every change at the website is not visible.
I empty the cache and tried to change some texts and every change was visible.
The plug-ins installed are:

- Akismet
- Contact Form 7
- iThemes Security
- Roots Rewrites
- Soil
- W3 Total Cache
- WordPress SEO
- WPML Media
- WPML Multilingual CMS
- WPML String Translation

I can't understand how resolve this problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With these informations, we can only say that you must look at Wordpress Codex:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in

Maybe you accidentally hid some sections for not logged in users. If not, please be more spesific about your question.

Answer (score 0):

## Sorry, I can't see the "user logged in" function.

the code that I add is this

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row"> 
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2  col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <hr/> 
        <h2 style="text-align: center;"><?php _e('Charter of services','fratesole'); ?><br/>
        <small><?php _e('Private Hospital','fratesole'); ?></small></h2>
        <p style="text-align: center;"><a class=" btn btn-primary" href="#" target="_blank" ><?php _e("Download Pdf","fratesole"); ?></a></p>
        <hr class="in-btn"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```